# Joomla K2 user extra fields

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I managed to add in extra fields in the default Joomla user component, but how do I add extra fields onto K2 Users component?

Example: I would like to add the fields "Website" and "Home address", then at the frontend, user is allowed to do the editing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a built in feature in K2. Extra fields are specific to categories only. Luckily, there is an extension that does exactly what you are looking for.

http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free/user-extended-fields-for-k2

Comment: Thanks, I tried the extension but then I can't add new custom fields to it. 
Is there any way I can do so? Other than the fields provided by the K2 extended fields. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Unfortunately the only way would be to modify the plugin to include what ever custom fields you would like to include.